# Why String concatenation of extracted file names does not work?

Tags: bash

I have a file "a.txt", that contains file names with paths.

a.txt:

```
/root/chan/properties.lo  
/root/attributes.cc   
/root/chan/eagle/bath.ear
```

I would like to extract these file names and put them in one variable this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat a.txt);  do
    o+=$(basename $i)
done

echo $o
```

But it does not work. 
I am geting:

```
feedBackMailConfiguration.xmltiess
```

Please, help.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you sure you're showing us your a.txt?  What version of bash?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r i;
do
   o=$o" "$(basename $i)
done < a.txt

echo $o
```

The above will do it.
(edits for copy and paste errors)

More edits: just tried this (terminator, ubuntu) and it give the right result:

```
while read -r i; do o="$o $(basename $i)";done < a.txt
```

Comment: @vladinkoc: and if you change `$o` to `${o}` ? and have a `o=''` before the while loop?

Comment: `while read -r i; do o=$o" "$(basename $i); echo "$i $(basename $i)";done < a.txt` Just done the following on the comamnd line.

Comment: and $0 is: `/bin/bash bath.ear properties.lo attributes.cc bath.ear`

Comment: the "read -r" may interfere, being too "raw". I put an answer up, taking the same idea but using your own loop, to have it closer to what you already tried.

Comment: better this works: `while read -r i; do o="$o $(basename $i)";done < a.txt` putting the setting in quotes.

Comment: @PAntoine: oops, you're right ^^ I should have tried... the space in $o will break the assignement if we don't quote it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a space concatenation to your script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat a.txt);  do
    # Check the " " at the end of the following line  
    o+=$(basename $i)" "
done

echo $o
```

And it would work

Comment: Unfortunatelly it also doesn't work. Maybe it's caused by bash version.

Comment: Can you execute the following? `for i in $(cat a.txt); do echo $i; done`

Comment: Well, that's a step, now, try to execute the following: `for i in $(cat a.txt); do basename $i; done`

Comment: Yes, this displays files correctly without paths. But I would like to have all of them in one variable. Because I need to compare it with variable gained from another file, that has different file paths, but the same file names.

Comment: Good, now try this: `for i in $(cat a.txt); do o=$o" "basename $i; done; echo $o`

Answer (score 0):

"o+=..." is not really portable (which version of bash allows it? I never saw it until your mention of it? It looks like perl mechanisms)

Edit2 : following vladintok remarks on what the output is, I add DEBUG infos to try to pinpoints the problem

Edit3 : another step of trying to take out of the way every possible explanation for the weird output reported... I unalias, and unset any function named "o" and "basename" ...

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
unalias o         2>/dev/null 
unalias basename  2>/dev/null
unset o           2>/dev/null
unset basename    2>/dev/null
for i in $(cat a.txt);  do
    printf 'DEBUG: i is: %s\n' "$i"
    o="${o} $(basename $i)"
done

printf 'DEBUG: final o is: %s\n' "$o"
echo $o
#end of the script.
```

(of course the above is a SINGLE file. Name it 'test.bash", make it executable: `chmod +x test.bash`, and then execute it : `./test.bash`)

Edit1: I corrected the `o=$o" "$(basename $i)` into `o="${o} $(basename $i)"` as pointed out by Pantoine. Otherwise,  toto=$toto" "titi  : would assign to toto everything until the first space (which will be somewhere inside $toto, after the first iteration or if a basename contained spaces)...

Comment: This will work also in ksh, and I believe in sh (not 100% sure, as "$(...)" may be only for "recent" versions)

Comment: According to [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) `bash` introduced the `+=` operator in `3.1-alpha1` which was around 2005-ish. `ksh` has known it since `00-03-30`, see the [changelog](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/gen/ast-ksh.html).

Comment: @vladinkoc: I based this on the assumption your own loop would work : if you replace the `o=${o}" "$(basename $i)` with `echo "file: $i"` : does it, indeed, show the full file(s)+path from your a.txt file? if not, what does it show?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: thanks, I didn't knew (and as I work on bash 2.x on some servers, I won't use it ^^)

Comment: @vladinkoc: I corrected thanks to Pantoine (credit should go to him, I should have noticed that myself but I did not ^^)

Comment: @OlivierDulac When I replaced the o=${o}" "$(basename $i) with echo "file: $i", it shows the full file(s)+path from a.txt file.

Comment: @vladinkoc: please try the new version (from yesterday), as i was placing the quotes (") incorrectly. It should work[Tm]. If you have spaces in the file names, then the $(cat a.txt) will spit out portions of filenames. Pantoine version should still work (or you also could get mine to work by tinkering with IFS)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Unfortunatelly it does not work.
Response is: 
feedBackMailConfiguration.xmltiess

Comment: @vladinkoc: then you need to do 2 things:  1) insert a line between `.... do` and `o="${o} $(basename $i)"` that have: `printf 'DEBUG: i=%s\n' "${i}"` . And in the end, have an additionnal line outputting the value of o :  `printf 'DEBUG: o is: %s\n' "$o"`. I'll edit to reflect this. This can point out things (I suspect there are "*" or similar chars in the a.txt that make `echo $o` interpret those * and expand them

Comment: Result is:
DEBUG: i=/root/chan/properties.lo
DEBUG: i=/root/attributes.cc
DEBUG: i=/root/chan/eagle/bath.ear
 feedBackMailConfiguration.xmltiess
 feedBackMailConfiguration.xmltiessde.properties

Comment: @vladinkoc: thanks. This means the loop is working, but it does NOT do the rest? Weird... Try my new script, which makes extra effort to ensure `basename` and `o` are really the things we expect them to be...  Please copy/paste the exact thing above (the greyed background section) and paste it into 1 file, named 'test.bash', make it executable, and then: `./test.bash`  to start it. As otherwise I could only assume you only put the loop in the script and forgot to put in the last 3 lines!